# How to escape slashes in regex?

Tags: php, regex

I've made some regex to test for a YouTube embedded video:

```
/^(http:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/embed\/)[^\/\s\\]+$/
```

It works for what I expect when I test it, but the problem though is that I need to pass that regex as a string to some function. Particularly I'm using htmlawed, where I pass a following string to a function:

```
func('iframe=-*,src(match="/^(http:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/embed\/)[^\/\s\\]+$/")');
```

The problem is that the above regex sort of works, but it just ignores the slashes, and accepts anything in place of them.

That is why I suspect that there is a problem with escaping.

I would appreciate if you could advice some alternative ways of escaping these slashes and backslashes... there must be some way?

Comment: That library might need its own escaping; try `\\\/`.

Comment: Which language. Which code? Is that a string definition? If so, what is the code of it? You need to provide actual source-code otherwise the question is not precise which makes it hard to answer.

Comment: None of that seem to work... I'll keep trying again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a string, you will need to escape the backslashes (and quotes) for the string literal. Or, depending on how the function builds the regex from the string, you might not need to escape slashes at all (I don't think so here).

```
"iframe=-*,src(match=\"/^(http:\\/\\/www\\.youtube\\.com\\/embed\\/)[^\\/\\s\\\\]+$/\")"
```

Comment: the slashes need to be escaped, otherwise something like this \// next to the site name would invaliade the match. I 'll keep trying with the above suggestions though

Comment: with single slashes though: `'iframe=-*,src(match="/^(http:\\/\\/www\\.youtube\\.com\\/embed\\/)[^\\/\\s\\\\]+$/")'`

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you can also use a different regex delimiter:

```
~^(http://www\.youtube\.com/embed/)[^/\s\\\\]+$~
```

Comment: yeah, that might be a good idea as long as we deal with urls, I'll keep it in mind for a future

Comment: @Bergi: No need to double the backslashes in a PHP regex *except for*  the one case where a literal backslash is required.

Comment: I thought the regex you wrote would be inside the OPs string - because you did double the backslashes inside the character class.

Comment: @Bergi: Just for the literal backslash. And yes, that regex is supposed to be inside a string literal. For example, to match a whitespace character, followed by a backslash, you could write `preg_match('/\s\\\\/', $subject)`...

Comment: So the single backslash with a non-escapable character (`s`, `.`) behind will make it backslash plus character in the string?